# How to design backend API for single Angular page refreshing certain components on the same page

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to .Net Core WebApi development and now have a question. The frontend is developed by my colleague using Angular.

What we want is, when the user firstly visits the page (a **GET** request), only two comboboxes and a button appear in the page. User selects options in comboboxes and click the button. The combiniton of two selected values will be sent to backend for checking (a **POST** request). Exists or not, the frontend will show a table. If exists then all the related values will be sent to frontend and displayed in the table. If not then the table will be empty (another **GET** request).

Now what I do not understand is how to design the API. Should I develop two GET and one POST methods with same urls, as shown below? But how would the frontend know which GET method should be called?

```
[Route('users/')]

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNumber()
{
//return data of the two comboboxes
}


[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTable(string username)
{
//get data to display the table
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckNumber([FromBody] User user)
{
//check if the combiniton of the two selected value exists in database
}
```

Or for the second GET request I use a new url like `/users/[combined values]`?

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

In your description, the first `get` request can be used to return options value for User selects options in comboboxes.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNumber()
{

//return data of the two comboboxes

}
```

You can directly use the `post` request to return the query results of the data required by the table and the logical judgment you need without having to configure a second `get` request.

```
   [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ReturnResult([FromBody] User user)
        {
            //1.define a collection or table instance.

            //2.check if the combiniton of the two selected value exists in database

            //3. based on the combiniton value to query data

            //4. set values for previously defined collections based on query data.

            //5.return the collection to the frontend 

        }
```

Finally, in the frontend side, based on the return data to show the table or empty.

Comment: shall I use OK(data) or CreateAtRoute("GetTable",new {result=data},data) to return the collection to the frontend? To me they are similar in this case.

Comment: `OK` is used to return a response with HTTP status code 200. It indicates that the request was successfully processed but no new resource was created. It is usually used when the client requests to obtain a resource. The `CreatedAtRoute` method is used to return a response with HTTP status code 201. It is usually used to indicate that a resource was successfully created and the URI of the new resource was included in the Location header of the response. It is usually used when the client creates a new resource. Normally we can return data to the front end using return OK or JSONresult

Comment: thanks for the detailed explainantion